# How to combine routing and templating?

Tags: php, oop, url, routes, templating

So, I've created a webshop system. It all worked perfectly, except for that projects can always be improved. So someone told me that 'Templating' and 'Routing' would be nice improvements. I've written classes for both of them, and they work fine! Now, I do wish to know how to combine them? How can I combine these classes so that data from the routing (to determine the content) needs to be placed inside the template. How would I do this?

Templating class:

```
class Template
    {
        private $assignedValues = array();
        private $tpl;

        /*
        **  @description    Creates one single instance of itself and checks whether the template file exists.
        **  @param  $path   [string]    This is the path to the template
        */
        public function __construct($_path = '')
        {
            if(!empty($_path)){
                if(file_exists($_path)){
                    $this->tpl = file_get_contents($_path);
                }
                else{
                    echo '<b>Template Error:</b> File Inclusion Error.';
                }
            }
        }

        /*
        **  @description    Assign a value to a part in the template.
        **  @param  $_searchString   [string]    This is the part in the template that needs to be replaced
        **  @param  $_replaceString   [string]    This is the code/text that will replace the part in the template
        */
        public function assign($_searchString, $_replaceString)
        {
            if(!empty($_searchString)){
                $this->assignedValues[strtoupper($_searchString)] = $_replaceString;
            }
        }

        /*
        **  @description    Shows the final result of the page.
        */
        public function show()
        {
            if(count($this->assignedValues > 0)){
                foreach ($this->assignedValues as $key => $value) {
                    $this->tpl = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->tpl);
                }
            }

            echo $this->tpl;

        }

        /*
        **  @description    Quickly load a part of the page
        **  @param  $quickLoad   [string]    This is the name of the file that will be loaded and assigned
        **  @param  $_searchString   [string]    This is the part in the template that needs to be replaced
        */
        public function quickLoad($_searchString, $part)
        {
            if(file_exists(INCLUDES.DS.$part.'.php')){
                $this->assign($_searchString,include(INCLUDES.DS.$part.'.php'));
            }
            else{
                return "That file does not exist!";
            }
        }

    }
```

And the routing class:

```
class Route
{
    protected $controller = 'App';

    protected $method = 'Call';

    protected $params = [];

    /*
    **  @description    Loads the classes and methods which are referred to.
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if($this->checkUrl())
        {
            unset($url[0]);

            if(isset($url[1]))
                {
                    if (file_exists('core/classes/' . $url[1] . '.class.php')) 
                    {
                        $this->controller = $url[1];
                        unset($url[1]);
                    }
                }

            require_once('core/classes/' . $this->controller . '.class.php');
            $this->controller = new $this->controller;

            if (isset($url[2])) 
            {
                if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[2])) 
                {
                    $this->method = $url[2];
                    unset($url[2]);
                }
            }

            $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
            $this->arrayUrl($this->params);

            call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
        }
    }

    /*
    **  @description    Check whether the URL part contains a string
    */
    public function checkUrl($index = '0',$value = 'Route'){
        $url = $this->parseUrl();
        if($url[$index] == $value){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
    **  @description    Splits the url into pieces.
    */
    protected function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])) 
        {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim(urldecode($_GET['url']), '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }

    /*
    **  @description    Sets arrays in routes.
    */
    protected function arrayUrl($params = array())
    {
        foreach($params as $index => $param)
        {
            if (preg_match('/>/',$param))  
            {
                $newParam = explode('>', $param);
                unset($this->params[$index]);
                $this->params['fields'][$newParam[0]] = $newParam[1];

            }
            else{
                unset($this->params[$index]);
                $this->params[] = $param;
            }
        }
        print_r($this->params);
    }
}
```

I can access my routes by URL's like this:
http://localhost:8080/Webshop/Route/*User*/**logout**
With: *Class* & **Method**.

This is a simple example that I already use, because no data needs to be showed using this method. It only logs out the user that is logged in. After that, you get redirected to the home page. But how could I use routing for other pages? For example, update some user data without having to create an update file?

### EDIT:

This is an example of a page I use now (index.php):

```
<?php
    /*
    **  @description    Includes config.php once so that we can use classes, defines etcetera.
    */
    require_once('core/preferences/config.php');

    /*
    **  @description    Instanciate new route object.
    */
    $route = new Route();

    /*
    **  @description    Check if a route isset. When not, continue, else: run route
    */
    if(!$route->checkUrl())
        {

            /*
            **  @description    Instanciate new template object.
            */
            $template = new Template(TEMPLATES_PATH .'/camerashop24.tpl.html');

            /*
            **  @description    Assign values.
            */
            $template->assign('title', 'Home');
            $template->assign('root', '');
            $template->quickLoad('loginout', 'loginout');
            $template->quickLoad('title_block', 'title_block');
            $template->quickLoad('cart','cart');
            $template->quickLoad('menu', 'menu');
            $template->assign('page', 'Home');

            $breadcrumbs = new Breadcrumbs($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'');
            $template->assign('breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs->data());

            $content = "";
            foreach(explode(",",Config::get('settings/front_page_cat')) as $item) {
                $content .= "<div id='blue-box' class='blue-box'><h2 style='color: white;'>" . strtoupper($item) . "</h2></div>";

                $category = new Category();
                $category->find($item);

                if($category->exists($item)){
                    foreach (explode(",",$category->data()->products) as $item) {
                        $product = new Product($item);
                        $product->find($item);
                        $content .= '<a href="Product/' . $product->data()->type . '">' . $product->showProduct($product->data()->type,$product->data()->name,$product->data()->price) . '</a>';
                    }
                }               
            }

            $template->assign('text', $content);
            $template->quickLoad('footer','footer');

            /*
            **  @description    Showing content.
            */
            $template->show();

        }
```

But, what I want as an answer, how can I show the data from the routing (select users profile for example) in this template without having to create a page for it like this one.

Comment: So, in your example URL above, "User" is the class, and "logout" is the method. Your templating class would be used in the logout method. In the method, you would call it as `new Template()` passing it your view's file location as a parameter.  Maybe im not following correctly? Is that what youre trying to find out?

Comment: I've edited my question in hope it becomes a little more clearer to you

Answer (score 1):

I think you're gonna have to modify your Routing class. Ideally you want the routing class to give YOU the ability to tell it what controller the route should use. Th controller you select would act as the middle man for processing. Each controller's method would represent a route, something like this:

```
/**
 * URL = www.test.com/index.php/home
 * URL = www.test.com/index.php/about
 * 
 * ROUTE Class:
 *  - should define routes. Example:
 *    
 *    $route["/home"] = MainController/home
 *    $route["/about"] = MainController/about
 *    $route["/*"] = MainController/*
 * 
 */



class MainController
{

    public function home()
    {
        $template = new Template(TEMPLATES_PATH . 'home.tpl.html');
        $template->show();
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $template = new Template(TEMPLATES_PATH . 'about.tpl.html');
        $template->show();
    }
}
```